# C++ `std::sort` over pointer to 2D data without copying

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, std

I have a large amount of data (GiB to TiB) in a C-style array of 2D data. It is not an array-of-arrays but instead a pointer to data that is interpreted as 2D data. It is very large so I do not want to copy it to `std::vector`s or similar. I cannot control the source of the data, it comes from an external library.

I need to `std::sort` the rows of the data based on the data in the columns (not quite lex-sort, but similar concept).

I have figured out how to do it with a compile-time known number of columns. For example:

```
#define COLUMNS 4
struct Row {
    double values[COLUMNS];
};

double* data = ...;
size_t n_rows = ...;
size_t n_cols = COLUMNS;

std::sort((Row*)data, ((Row*)data)+n_rows, comp);
```

I know I can template the struct for `COLUMNS` instead of using a macro and instead of using `comp` could define the `operator<` than in the `Row` struct but that doesn't change the compile-time nature of the number of columns*.

The only solution I can think of is to use a custom random-access iterator that knows the stride of each row. But before I make my own iterator (which is always a bit daunting to me) I want to make sure there is no other way.

*These design choices were made due to the fact I am actually writing this in Cython and not C++, but that shouldn't matter, I can't figure out how to do this with C++ without a custom iterator. I am willing to write solutions in C++ but prefer options that can be written Cython (I can convert).

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`ing this way causes UB, if I remember correctly. I'd write a custom iterator. Alternatively, if you just want a simple solution, good ol' `std::qsort` should work.

Comment: You are using C++ so do not write this in C style. Replace define with regular constant. Use `std::array` and/or `std::vector` (for example `std::vector<std::array<double>>`) and write this without casting. Do not make your life hard since you seen such bad code in some other places. Provide [this link](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk) to your C++ teacher.

Comment: Another option would be to create an array of pointers to rows, and then sort the array of pointers. Once the pointers are sorted, they can be used to reorder the data  (will also return pointers to their original state) in O(n) (linear) time. I can post example code if interested. The compare would still need to know the number of columns per row, perhaps using a global variable.

Comment: What problem do you have with your code? And how is defined `comp`?

Comment: @MarekR This is not homework, in fact I am a CS teacher. Read the note I put in for why this is written this way. The library I am use gives a double pointer, no controlling that. You seem to have not read the question that using `std::vector` and `std::array` are not acceptable since they will copy the data.

Comment: @Phil1970 The problem is stated that the number of columns is compile-time and not run-time driven. The implementation of `comp` should be unimportant, but I have that working.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In my initial tests `std::qsort` is about half as fast as `std::sort` for this problem. Additionally, `std::qsort` would need to use a global variable for the number of columns, better than a compile-time constant but still not optimal. The `reinterpret_cast` is also a side-effect of it being actually Cython. The `double *` is properly aligned so it should not cause aliasing issues.

Comment: @rcgldr this is good since I actually do need to perform an indirect sort, I am handling that part in a weird way right now, but your way is likely better. A global variable for number of columns won't be necessary since a functor can be used for `comp` instead of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code showing the reorder in place in O(n) time below. You'll need to change *pa[i]-a* which converts a pointer to index to deal with the actual structure for a[].

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool compare(const double *p0, const double *p1)
{
    return *p0 < *p1;
}

int main()
{
double a[8] = {8.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,2.0};
double *pa[8];
size_t i, j, k;
double ta;
    // create array of pointers to a[]
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        pa[i] = &a[i];
    // sort array of pointers to a[]
    std::sort(pa, pa+sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), compare);
    // reorder a[] and pa[] according to pa[] in O(n) time
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
        if(i != pa[i]-a){
            ta = a[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = pa[k]-a)){
                a[k] = a[j];
                pa[k] = &a[k];
                k = j;
            }
            a[k] = ta;
            pa[k] = &a[k];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

The reorder in place works by undoing the "cycles" in pa[] sorted according to a[]. For this example code, a list of indices 0 to 7 followed by a list of pa[i]-a for i = 0 to 7 results in:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    (i)
2 7 5 6 4 1 3 0    (pa[i] - a)
```

This shows the "cycles" in pa[] sorted according to a[]. Starting with the 0 in the (i) line, the index below it is 2. Looking at the 2 in the i line, the number below it is a 5. Below 5 is a 1. Below 1 is a 7. Below 7 is a 0, completing that cycle. Using -> to note the next index, there are 3 cycles in this case:

```
{0->2->5->1->7->0} {3->6->3} {4->4}
```

What the reorder in place does is undo the cycles for both a[] and pa[]. It finds the first cycle at pa[0] (i != pa[i]-a). Looking at a[], you have ta=a[0], a[0]=a[2], a[2] = a[5], a[5]=a[1], a[1]=a[7], at this point i == 0 == pa[7]-a, the last part of the cycle and it sets a[7] = ta. pa[] is updated in the same manner. The next cycle is ta=a[3], a[3]=a[6], a[6] = ta. The last cycle, 4->4 points to itself, so is skipped (i == pa[i]-a). The time complexity for this is O(n).

There's a youtube video about permutations and cycle notation (in this case it would be (0,2,5,1,7)(3,6) (the (4) is ignored since it's in place). You can do a web search for "permutation cycle" for other articles.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpKG6FmcIHk

Comment: While the global idea is probably adequate, I think there are a few errors or unclear things:
- `ta` is not declared
- the `reorder` part seems complex. Maybe you should give some explanation or at least try to find better variable names.

Comment: @Phil1970 - `ta` is declared as double, the last non-indented line in main(). I updated my answer to explain reorder in place according to a set of indices.

Comment: This is good. I did one step further in my own version that used an array of indices instead of pointers (so I could actually have multiple arrays for the columns) and used a functor for the comparison. The finding all the right positions is actually done for me. Thanks for pointing out using an indirect sort.

Comment: @coderforlife - The pointers are an alternative to using a functor or Lambda compare. I wasn't sure of the limitations of Cython. I have examples that use an array of indexes with a Lambda compare to do essentially what you describe, but usually to sort multiple arrays based on sorting one of the arrays (generate and sort indexes to the one array, then reorder all of the arrays in place using the reorder logic in my example code).

Comment: @coderforlife if you had the space, you could simply create another array, using b[i] = a[sortedindex[i]]. The indirect sort is not complicated using either pointers, functors, or Lamda compare, but the reorder in place algorithm is not as well known.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick. Define `Row` as a pointer to the beginning of a row, like so:

```
struct Row {
   double* start;
   static int columns;

   Row(const Row& row) = default;

   // Overload operator= to copy your data.
   Row& operator=(const Row& rhs) {
      memcpy(start, rhs.start, columns*sizeof(double));
   }

   Row operator<(const Row& rhs) const {
      // your comparison function
   }
};
```

Use like so:

```
double* data = ...;
size_t n_rows = ...;
size_t n_cols = COLUMNS;
Row::columns = n_cols;

std::vector<Row> rows(n_rows);
for(int i=0;i<n_rows;++i) {
   rows[i].start = data + i*n_cols;
}
std::sort(rows.begin(), rows.end());
```

You'll need to create a `std::vector<Row>`. Hopefully you don't have so many rows so that's a performance issue.

Comment: @coderforlife This doesn't copy the data. It creates an array of pointers to the starts of each row, and sorts that. So if you have N columns, you're going to be sorting 1/N the data.

Comment: You are right that it doesn't make a full copy, but it will cause copies at some point (otherwise why is a copy constructor required?) and I think that `sort` copies each row as it is swapping them, which is a ton of copying even if not taking significant additional memory.

Comment: @coderforlife It should do the exact same copying as your original solution with fixed columns, or the iterator you mentioned, or a call to qsort. I took your question to be about how to support a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and you are right and I was wrong. You have made me realize that my current solution doesn't even fit my own requirements.